# Replacing Tag in Partially Unstructured Data using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

In the below example I would like to replace `<break/>` tags with `<br />`, or at minimum return all text (including the `<break/>`s) so I may replace the `<break/>`s with Javascript.

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<document xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
          xsi:schemaLocation='http://www.lotus.com/dxl xmlschemas/domino_8_5_3.xsd'
          xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl' >

<item name='item1'>
    <textlist>
        <text/>
    </textlist>
</item>
<item name='item2'>
    <textlist>
        <text>This<break/>is<break/>a<break/>broken<break/>sentence.<break/></text>
    </textlist>
</item>
</document>
```

EDIT:
I would also only like to return the results of item2, ignoring item1 altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An really small [Identity transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) should do.
The only small "trick" here is to consider the namespaces.
Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:dxl='http://www.lotus.com/dxl'
                xmlns='http://www.lotus.com/dxl'

                 exclude-result-prefixes='dxl'  >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dxl:break">
        <br>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <br >
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the follwing output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.lotus.com/dxl" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.lotus.com/dxl xmlschemas/domino_8_5_3.xsd">

    <item name="item1">
        <textlist>
            <text/>
        </textlist>
    </item>
    <item name="item2">
        <textlist>
            <text>
                This<br/>is<br/>a<br/>broken<br/>sentence.<br/>
            </text>
        </textlist>
    </item>
</document>
```

**Update** to additional question to ignore "item1"
Add following line to the style sheet:

```
<xsl:template match ="dxl:item[@name='item1']" />
```

Or if only "item2 should be in the output, add a root template:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/dxl:item[@name='item2']" />
    </document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I omitted part of my criteria from my original post. Could you please help address the edit question?

Comment: @NickBetcher; Thank you for fixing. But I would suggest to stay with the opening closing `<br>` because it would generate a single one if there is no content in `<break>`. But the template with single br will throw an exception if there is content in break. If you like to have always the single br you should also remove the apply-tmeplates form break templage